Problem submitting Bing API search request from apps script
I'm implementing the bing api search in google apps script.
I've tried this approach:
var url =https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search?key=[appkey]&q=Bart's%20Heating%20%26%20Air
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
And this approach:
var url = https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search?q=Bart's%20Heating%20%26%20Air
var options = {
'method': 'GET',
'headers': {
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': apiKey
}
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
In both cases, the error I'm getting is:  "Exception: Request failed for https://api.bing.microsoft.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"error":{"code":"401","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an acti..."
My subscription is active, the API key was copied from Azure settings and I believe endpoint is correct.
Any ideas what the problem might be?

Please check this doc of Bing Search API documentation

The problem ended up being terminology.  All 3 of the code samples refer to a subscription key not an api key.  Since there is no api key on the main Azure settings page for a web search, I used the subscription id.  After I found and used one of the api keys on the Manage keys page things are now working fine.

The error 401 - Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint occurs because the URL contains the instance's configuration ID.
var endpoint = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/";
 var url = endpoint + "/v7.0/custom/images/search?" + "q=" + searchTerm + "&customconfig=" + customConfigId

Create a Bing Custom Search in Azure, copy the BING_CUSTOM_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY. You can obtain the customConfigId from this link.
The API call will be as follows:
export BING_CUSTOM_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY="your_subscription_key_here"
 export YOUR_CUSTOM_CONFIG_ID="your_custom_config_id_here"

curl --header "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $BING_CUSTOM_SEARCH_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY""https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/custom/search?q=car&customconfig=$YOUR_CUSTOM_CONFIG_ID&mkt=en-US"

Below is the code for making a custom search request using the Bing API with Axios.
const axios = require('axios');

const subscriptionKey = ' Your_Bing_API_subscription_key'; 
const customConfig = 'Your_custom_config_ID'; 
const query = 'car'; 
const market = 'en-US'; 

const url = `https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/custom/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}&customconfig=${customConfig}&mkt=${market}`;

axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log('Search Results:', response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
    if (error.response) {
        
        console.error('Error Response:', error.response.data);
        console.error('Status Code:', error.response.status);
    } else if (error.request) {
       
        console.error('Error Request:', error.request);
    } else {
       
        console.error('Error Message:', error.message);
    }
});

Output:

Refer to this document for Bing Custom Search in C#. Additionally, check this git for information on how to add Bing web search capabilities to your application.

Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I omitted in my post that I'm using the web search api not the custom search api.
According to the web search api documentation the proper endpoint is: https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-web-search/reference/endpoints).
The problem ended up being terminology.  All 3 of the code samples refer to a subscription key not an api key.  Since there is no api key on the main settings page I used the subscription id.  After I found and used one of the api keys things are now working fine.
